# Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{z_n}{w_n}=\frac{z}{x}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{z_n}{w_n}=\frac{z}{x}$ where $z_n, w_n\in\mathbb{C}$

Where $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{z_n}=z$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{w_n}=w$

**My work**

Let $\epsilon>0$

By hypothesis, we have exists $N_1\,, N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N_{1,2}$ then $|z_n-z|<\epsilon |w_n|$ and $|w_n-w|<\epsilon$

Then,
$|\frac{z_n}{w_n}-\frac{z}{w}|=|\frac{z_n.w-z.w_n}{w_n.w}|=|\frac{1}{w_n}||z_n-z|<\epsilon$

Is correct my argument?

Comment: What if $w=0$? How do you get that first inequality (which is actually several inequalities)?

Comment: The case $w=x=z=0$ should be considered with care, or eliminated.

Comment: Which inequality @RobertWolfe? Thanks

Comment: $|z_n-z|<\epsilon|w_n|$

Comment: Well, $|w_n|$ is only a real number, i only take epsilon of that form. @RobertWolfe

Comment: $|w_n|$ is not a fixed real number. It changes for each $n$.